# How to trace specific functions/files in C?

Tags: c, function, gcc

I have already known that the GCC's argument `-finstrument-functions` can hook the functions and the argument `-finstrument-functions-exclude-file(functions)-list` can exclude some files/functions to be traced.

But now I have a lot of files to be compiled and only some of them need to be traced. I wonder if I can include some specific functions/files to be traced, such as something like `-finstrument-functions-include-file(functions)-list`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you plan something that can't be done with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

GCC does not support this out-of-the-box (it's more a task for your build system). One common hack to achieve what you want is to write a shell wrapper which replaces GCC and adds flags where needed:

```
$ cat path/to/fake/gcc
#!/bin/sh
FLAGS=
if echo "$*" | grep -q 'myfile1.c'; then
  FLAGS=-finstrument-functions
fi
exec /usr/bin/gcc "$@" $FLAGS
$ export PATH="path/to/fake:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use cmake to build your project you may benefit from adding COMPILE_OPTIONS at a specific level. Use

```
add_compile_options()
```

for directory-wide settings

```
target_compile_options()
```

for target-specific settings and

```
set_source_files_properties()
```

for file specific settings.

In your case

```
set_source_files_properties( 
 myfile1.cc  PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS  -finstrument-functions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers can be extended by [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

> But now I have a lot of files to be compiled and only some of them need to be traced.

You should consider writing your own GCC plugin to do that job. See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

You may configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) to help you.

At last, some of your C code (e.g. `#include`-ed files) could be generated. Think of meta-programming approaches (e.g. with [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or your own C code generator), perhaps using [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).